# What's a saying for "talking bad in someone's ear"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, popular-refrains

There's a saying I'm thinking of. Let's say I worked on your car and you were happy with it. Then your friend told you that the work was dissatisfactory and making up things to change your opinion, as you previously thought the work was fine.

"tainting your thoughts" or something. Basically whispering in your ear to change your opinion.

Comment: correction: unsatisfactory. This question belongs on ELL not here. :)

Comment: @Lambie what is ELL?

Comment: It's the English Language Learner site.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of phrases and some words:

- to poison one's mind against someone or something
- to plant a seed of doubt in someone's mind
- *bad-mouthing* or one of its [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bad-mouthing) [M-W].

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/poison+(one)+against+(someone+or+something)
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/plant-an-idea-doubt-suspicion-in-somebody-s-mind

Comment: I think your three examples each represent a level of severity.  *Planting a seed of doubt* can be accomplished with one word.  *Poisoning one's mind* would likely take a quite a bit of time, the implication being that a change of mind must take place.  *Bad mouthing* best represents the OP's example.  The bad mouther provides enough information to suggest that the work on the car was bad, even though some of that is made-up.  Bad-mouthing is more vigorous than planting a seed of doubt but far from poisoning anyone's mind.

Comment: Iago in Othello says "I'll pour this pestilence into his ear" and there are a lot of similar expressions with poison, toxins, etc, going in ears and minds. I'm not sure which is the exact best phrase.